# How to Write images src and class using response.write method

Tags: c#-3.0

```
 <%Response.Write("<img class="lazy" src=img_cart/image28/" + Session["image1"] + ".jpg" + "   />"); %>
```

This code gives `error only assignment,call,increment,decrement, and new object
expressions can be used as a statement.`

So how to write images src and class using response.write method like this:

```
 <%Response.Write("<img class="lazy" src=img_cart/image28/" + Session["image1"] + ".jpg" + "   />"); %>
```

Expected end result:

```
 <img class="lazy" src="img_cart/image28/IMAGENAME.jpg" />
```

Comment: Consider editing your question. You ended up placing your code in a comment rather than the actual question.

Comment: response.Write("<img class="lazy" src=img_cart/image28/" + Session["image1"] + ".jpg" + " />") this gives us errors

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C#, the problem is that you must use escape chars because of the double quotes symbols `"` . They should be written as `\"` because they are contained in other double quotes. So try this:

```
<%Response.Write("<img class=\"lazy\" src=\"img_cart/image28/" + Session["image1"] + ".jpg\"  />"); %>
```

Comment: <%Response.Write("<img class=\"load-delay\" src=\"img_cart/image20/" + Session["image1"] + ".jpg"+"  />"); %>  Here how to incluede this alt="<%Response.Write(Session["Name"]);%>" in same example.

Comment: @Abhishek It would be the same way as `Session["image1"]`was used: `<%Response.Write("<img class=\"load-delay\" src=\"img_cart/image20/" + Session["image1"] + ".jpg\" alt=\""+ Session["Name"] +"\"    />"); %>`. Please, mark answer as accepted if it worked for you.